# Automapper Projections and Enum > string converter

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

Having a problem using Automapper's `Project().To` method that does not show up when doing a simple `Mapper.Map<>()`.

I have an enum that is mapped to a string, and a class containing that enum that is mapped to another class containing a string property with the same name as the enum property.

When I do a simple `Mapper.Map<>()` from one class to another, everything works fine. But when I  try to do a `Project().To()`, I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Type 'System.String' does not have a default construct
or
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(Type typeIn, Type typeOut)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(Type typeIn, Type typeOut)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.<CreateMapExpression>b__9[TSource,TDestination](T
ypePair tp)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Fu
nc`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression[TSource,TDestination]()
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression`1.To[TResult]()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Here's a code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        public static string DisplayName(this Enum e)
        {
            var field = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());
            if (field != null)
            {
                var display = ((DisplayAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (display != null)
                {
                    return display.Name;
                }
            }
            return e.ToString();
        }
    }

    public enum Foo
    {
        [Display(Name = "Thing 1")]
        Thing1,
        [Display(Name = "Thing 2")]
        Thing2
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public Foo SomeFoo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BarViewModel
    {
        public string SomeFoo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // map from enum value to enum display name
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, string>().ConvertUsing(x => x.DisplayName());
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarViewModel>();
                AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();


                List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
                bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = "Name1", SomeFoo = Foo.Thing2 });
                bars.Add(new Bar() { Name = "Name2", SomeFoo = Foo.Thing1 });


                var barsQuery = (from Bar b in bars
                                 select b).AsQueryable();

                // works exactly as expected
                var barViewModesls1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BarViewModel>>(barsQuery).ToList();

                // throws an exception "Type 'System.String' does not have a default constructor"
                var barViewModels2 = barsQuery.Project().To<BarViewModel>().ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("press a key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this ?

Comment: Sorry, it's c#, I added a tag to clarify

Comment: It doesn't help you, but I've recreated this in AutoMapper 2.2.1 as well as the the 3.0.0 pre-release. `Foo -> Foo` works, `Foo -> string` doesn't and nor does `string -> Foo`. I'd suggest raising it as an issue [on github project page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues?page=1&state=open). I also noticed you asked on their mailing list which is a good idea - they're pretty active there.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution directly. In my case, I wanted the string conversion for display purposes in the UI. Instead of converting the enum to string via AutoMapper, I'm using MVC display and editor templates that do the conversion at the UI and that's working well enough for me.